# how to show selected chekbox which are true in mongodb collection with node js ejs

Tags: node.js

<input id="myCheck"  class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="approve"  value="<%=row._id%>" <%= row.approve==true ? "checked" : "" %>>  is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<% let chk = row.approve ? 'checked' : '' %>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" name="approve" value="<%=row._id %>" <%=chk%>>
```